# Python cron job under windows7

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I have created a simple cron job under windows to run a very simple python scrape:

- scrape webpage
- store data into csv file
- close file

Cron job under Windows worked fine-without any probs. All of sudden, that cron job stopped working, my output file is not getting updated. When I run the scrape manually (double click on python file or via python IDE) I would typically get my debug output "everything ok" in a windows dialog window and the target file gets updated. During the cron job I can see that debug output window popping up and printing the same "everything ok" debug, but the file is just not getting updated.

I tried rebooting my machine, close/open all program. Created a new task in the scheduler, it still wouldn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Have you tried checking the permissions for the file in question, and the user under which the job runs?

Comment: Yes. All the same user. It is very strange: when running the script manually I get the right debug output and getting the same output for the task scheduler.It just that the file is not being updated when running it via the scheduler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with all potential settings in windows and many wasted hours I found a workaround.

My initial setup in the task manager was calling the python.exe and my python.py file was passed as an argument. Just as described here: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/. The difference at the end that made my cron job work again was that I deleted passing the python file as an argument and now calling python file directly. Not sure why the initial setup stopped working - but this has helped. Hope you don't get into the same time wasting situation.